# Question about representation of free products of groups.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

1. Does anyone have an idea of books or papers that treats representation theory    of free products of groups?
2. What properties of factors of of a free product suggest a possible representation? Examples will help.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems too vague to admit a real answer, but it might be useful to notice that a representation of a free product $G*H$ on a space $V$ is determined by just giving two representations on $V$, one representation of $G$ and one of $H$, with no required connection between the two representations.

Comment: That $G*H$-reps are really pairs of $G,H$-reps holds true for representations into any category, in fact.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you for the response. The vagueness of my question was intentional. This is because I wanted to see how people think about such representation. So I asked the second question to get something more specific.            I will like to ask you to elaborate on your answer by giving an example with G and H non-abelian finite groups.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ and $H$ have faithful representations over a field $K$, then $G*H$ has a faithful representation over some extension of $K$. See, for example,

Marciniak, Zbigniew S.
A note on free products of linear groups.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 94 (1985), no. 1, 46–48.

Summary: For a field $K$, let $\overline{K}$ denote its algebraic closure. Assume that $|\overline{K}:K|=\infty$. Then for any linear groups $G,H \subseteq GL_n(K)$ their free product $G∗H$ can be embedded into $GL_N(K(t))$. Here $N$ is an integer depending on $K$ only and $t$ stands for an indeterminate.

Comment: @Holt: Thank you for the link.